# IIS Web Platform Installer Error: 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 1, position 3

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, web-platform-installer

I've just created a new IIS website on a Windows Server 2008 in order to use it to deploy a new website.

 The website is still empty.

If I try to open IIS Web Platform Installer under Management Tools, I get stuck on the error:

> 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'.
>   Line 1, position 3.

After closing the error, the Web platform Installer closes.

Do anyone know how to solve it?

*Let me know in the comments if you need any other info or technical data, I have really no idea on how can I troubleshoot this*

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, here's how I solved.

This issue seems to be strictly related to an old configuration of this server, so I had to manually reset it. If you face this issue, these following steps should work fine:

- First of all, I had to remove the IIS role functionality from
  `Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Window Features on or
  off > Roles`.
- Then, I restarted the server and added again the IIS role
  functionality (make sure to check all of the asp net
  functionalities).
- After that, I restarted the server (again) and I have reinstalled: 
  1) DotNetCore.2.0.7-WindowsHosting (you've got to find the installer online, make sure to download the last version. 2.0.7 was the last when I made this question so on 25/05/2018) 
   2) Web platform Installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
- Executing web platform installer from all program inside start menu worked fine.

Hope it will be helpful

[*(See Also:
How to Install Web Platform Installer and Web Deployment)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)

Comment: Simply updating WebPlatformInstaller to the latest version was enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. However, I cannot uninstall IIS completely as I have many sites on my IIS running.

What I did was, I tried to install an IIS module which was not there. for eg, I chose CORS module.

You can get it from here https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Once I tried installing, WPI automatically uninstalled and reinstalled during the process and it resolved the issue.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [@qbik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829045/qbik) Simply updating the Web platform installer fixed the issue. You can download the latest at this time from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).